# SPI Bus Clock Slew Rate

Tags: spi, flash, signal-integrity, slew-rate

I am interfacing LPC1768 SPI bus and SST25VF016B SPI Serial Flash. Flash is 50Mhz, and these are the values I copied from [SPI Flash Datasheet.](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25044A.pdf) page 24.

FCLK (Serial Clock Frequency)  50 MHz

TSCKH (Serial Clock High Time)  9 ns

TSCKL (Serial Clock Low Time)  9 ns

TSCKR (Serial Clock Rise Time (Slew Rate))  0.1 V/ns

TSCKF (Serial Clock Fall Time (Slew Rate))  0.1  V/ns

There is also figure 26 on [page 28](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25044A.pdf) in the same data sheet, shows AC Test input rise/fall times are less than 5ns.

Why Clock Slew rate is so low(0.1 V/ns)? Doesn't it make clock rise and fall times very long?

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet specifies that as a minimum, so higher slew rates are certainly possible (and likely). But if you slew *slower* than that then the device may misbehave.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I should stop reading documentation for today :)

Comment: I thought the slew rate was a metric used to characterize the maximum rate at which the output can change over time. According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate), the slew rate is defined this way. What does a *minimum* slew rate even mean? The context I am familiar with slew rate is with OpAmps and with its use being to characterize the frequency response of the amplifier (to some extent).

Comment: @sherrellbc: Due to the [underlying analog nature of digital electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125356/is-micro-processor-completely-digital), inputs have a minimum slew rate that must be met in order to properly recognize a transition from a low to a high or vice versa; not meeting this minimum slew rate results in misbehavior of the circuit. Some digital logic has [compensation for lower slew rates](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103259/schmitt-trigger-action), and some does not.